# Stream collect list to map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a", "c");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Function.identity() ,
    Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
    ));
```

what it produces is

```
  {a=[a, a], b=[b], c=[c, c]}
```

Pretty please how should I write mapping method to get a Map that would give me:

```
{a=2, b=1, c=2}
```

Comment: You could start by changing `Map<String, List<String>> map` to `Map<String, Integer> map` - since you don't want a list of `String`(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Collectors.counting`

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

The above would give you a `Map<String, Long>`